# How to convert sty and files to LyX layout

Tags: lyx, packages

I need to import in Lyx the following layout: [`brain_damage.sty`](http://users.wfu.edu/cottrell/brain_damage.sty)

http://gregorywheeler.org/latex/phil-style1.html

How can I convert it to a format that LyX can understand?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Any particular reason to use this rather than `philosophy.sty` (which is already included in TeX Live, at least)? I don't use LyX but there is a way to edit the preamble of you document and you need to add `\usepackage{philosophy}` (or `\usepackage{brain_damage}`.

Comment: ^ It is not included in TeX Live. I just happen to have installed it. However, it does include some enhancements over `brain_damage`. (Basically, it is `brain_damage` + changes to make the maths fit better, if I remember right.)

Answer (score 1):

You can save [`brain_damage.sty`](http://users.wfu.edu/cottrell/brain_damage.sty) and [place it where (La)TeX can find it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764) and then include

```
\usepackage{brain_damage}
```

in your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble. Alternatively, copy-and-paste everything *between*

```
\ProvidesPackage{brain_damage}
...
\endinput
```

(that is, the `...` above) and place it directly in the Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.